# Changing the JSON output property dynamically in Java

Tags: java, json, rest

I want to set the property of output JSON as the input value, so for every request the property name would be changing.

This is the get Request url for my webservice:
`http://10.0.75.1:7001/polling/Z2074350/` -> `Z2074350` is the value for that I need to create JSON property:

How do I achieve this?

My Controller looks like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/batchpolling/{waybill}/{cp_id}", headers="Accept=application/json", produces="application/json")
    
public ResponseEntity<BatchPollingResponse> getBatchPollingResponse( @PathVariable("waybill") String waybill) throws JsonProcessingException {
            
        BatchPollingResponse batchPollResponse = null;
        try {
            ----------------------
            batchPollResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(url, BatchPollingResponse.class);
            ----------------------
        }catch(Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error processing OrderCreationMPS - getBatchPollingResponse");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return new ResponseEntity<BatchPollingResponse>( batchPollResponse, HttpStatus.OK );
        
    }
```

and my JSON output will be like:

```
"result": {
    "**Z2074350**": {
        "latest_status": {
             "status": "delivered"
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have dynamically property in response, just try to pass `Map<String, BatchPollingResponse>` in `ResponseEntity` object and as a key put your property.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/batchpolling/{waybill}/{cp_id}", headers="Accept=application/json", produces="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, BatchPollingResponse>> getBatchPollingResponse( @PathVariable("waybill") String waybill) throws JsonProcessingException {
            
        BatchPollingResponse batchPollResponse = null;
        try {
            ----------------------
            batchPollResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(url, BatchPollingResponse.class);
            ----------------------
        }catch(Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error processing OrderCreationMPS - getBatchPollingResponse");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return ResponseEntity.ok(Map.of(waybill, batchPollResponse));
        
    }
```

Comment: I've added more information in the question, could you please check once again and let me know where and what changes needed to achieve the required

Comment: @Charan can you also show a `BatchPoolingResponse` class?

Comment: public class BatchPollingResponse {
 
 private Meta meta;
 private BatchPollingResult result;
 
 public Meta getMeta() {
  return meta;
 }
 public void setMeta(Meta meta) {
  this.meta = meta;
 }
 public BatchPollingResult getResult() {
  return result;
 }
 public void setResult(BatchPollingResult result) {
  this.result = result;
 }
 
}

Comment: public class BatchPollingResult {
 
 private WayBillResponse waybill;
  
 public WayBillResponse getWaybill() {
  return waybill;
 }
 public void setWaybill(WayBillResponse waybill) {
  this.waybill = waybill;
 }
 
}

Comment: @Charan I suppose that in `wayBill` refrence has inside `latestStatus` reference, which has status property, right?

Try my updated post solution, above ^